# Slick carousel not initiating when showed with jQuery slideUp

Tags: jquery, slideup, slick.js

I'm using a [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with hidden status and a link to toggle it using jQuery slideUp/slideDown:

```
<a href="#" id="carousel-toggle"><span class="fa fa-navicon"></span></a>
<div id="carousel" style="display: none;">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div>your content 1</div>
        <div>your content 2</div>
        <div>your content 3</div>
        <div>your content 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.carousel').slick();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#carousel-toggle').on('click', function(){
        var content = $(this).parents().find('#carousel');
        if (content.is(':visible'))
            content.slideUp("slow");
        else
            content.slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Its working fine, but the first time i toggle the **#carousel** it shows all slides messed up, when i click the nav for the first time it start to work normally, and toggeling it dosent mess it up. But when i make the default status visible it initiates normally.

This JSFIDDLE explains it all: [http://jsfiddle.net/walidov/8Lfyfcut/](http://jsfiddle.net/walidov/8Lfyfcut/1/)

How can i make it intiate while the status is hidden?
Im using bootstrap3 by the way. But i need slick carousel since it has a great responsive method that bootstrap carousel dosent apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does seem to work is to hide the content with js instead of css after a short delay. The delay is there to give the slick some time to initiate.

```
setTimeout(function(){    
    var content = $('#carousel');
    content.slideUp(10);
}, 10);
```

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lfyfcut/12/

So, 2 things to note:
- The slick content is NOT set to "display: none" with the css
- The content gets hidden with js after a short delay (setTimeout()).